# How to do paging on redis's sets data structure?

Tags: caching, redis, set, paging

I want to use redis's sets data structure to store user's followers list, How I can do paging to fetch records from list based on page size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On top of what @Didier Spezia wrote, I'd also try to store the followers in a sorted set.

If you want them by name, store them all with score of 0, and then use [ZRANGEBYLEX](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) to page them lexically.

If you want by the order that they were added as friends, use the timestamp of addition as the score, and use [ZRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrange) to page them by time.

[EDIT] oh, another option to look at if memory concerns you: if the ids are constant length integers, you can store them as binary values in an array using a string key, and page it with ranges. It will be super fast and will have virtually 0 memory overhead. Have a look at the [BITFIELD](https://redis.io/commands/bitfield) command. It might be a very good use case for it, although it doesn't cover deletion and lookup, so if those are a concern it's not a good option.

Comment: I heard sorted sets are heavier in terms of consuming memory and processing, that is why I wanted to use sets, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: They are a bit heavier, but sets are not cheap either. There is a configuration option that optimizes memory for small sorted sets that can reuce memory up to 80%, have a look at redis.conf.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to leverage the [SSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/sscan) command. Make sure to understand how the SCAN command works first.